Новый способ сортировки: Trending
В сортировке вопросов появился новый пункт Trending:

Тема на английском SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/432435/8674428
Судя по описанию по ссылке, эта сортировка учитывает недавнюю активность в вопросе и ее количество. Но есть еще сортировка "Most activity" (она не видна в этом экране, только в фильтрах), которая немного от нее отличается. Нужно придумать, как переводить эти новые термины.

В тренде _

Тут 16 строк переводить надо: https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Trend

"Trending" -> "Популярные"?

"В тренде" как-то не по русски.

trending ~ тенденции("модные" темы, ну т.е. там должны быть популярные темы из самых популярных меток, но не уверен - надо проверять).  most activity ~ обязательна активность(мб там без "некро-правок""поднятий ботом" которые как раз всех уже и заколупали? :3 живые так сказать)

UPD most activity судя по выдаче ~= "протухшие"(очень популярные ранее но утратившие активность сейчас). trending - таки новые из популярных меток.

@чистов_n В тренде - так youtube сейчас переводит свою страницу "trending". Взгляните сами: https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending

Еще как вариант - "Набирающие популярность".

Предложил переводы на основе наилучших вариантов из комментариев:
Trending - Популярные
Trending questions - Популярные вопросы
Most activity - Наибольшая активность
Most active questions - Вопросы с наибольшей активностью
